# DatePicker in android layout causes a stackoverflow

Tags: java, android

When I try to add a DatePicker to my layout, whenever the activity is launched, it crashes with a stack overflow.

This is the layout that crashes when displayed on the emulator (renders fine in eclipse):

```
        </LinearLayout>
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout" android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dip">
            <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Date:" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"></TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <DatePicker android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/datePicker" android:duplicateParentState="true"></DatePicker>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout01">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Cancel" />
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnFinish" android:text="Finish" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it crashes with this stack trace:

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception StackOverflowError))    
    ViewRoot.draw(boolean) line: 1235   
    ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1030 
    ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1482  
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3948    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 782  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 540 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

When I comment out the DatePicker, it doesn't crash.

How can I actually get the DatePicker to not crash this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by getting rid of the superfluous `LinearLayout` parent of the `DatePicker`.

If that helps, or if the stack trace for your exception appeared to be in Android layout rendering code (e.g., calls to `layout()` and `onMeasure()` and such), you probably have too complex of a UI. Use Hierarchy Viewer to examine your activity -- if the longest path from the root container to the farthest leaf is much over 10, your UI is too complex. Simplify the user interface (e.g., switch from nested `LinearLayouts` to `RelativeLayout`, replace activities-in-tabs with views-in-tabs).

Comment: After decomplicating the layout, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what CommonsWare mentioned, have you tried running the layoutopt tool?  It often will give you very helpful comments about your layouts.